# Is there any Windows/Linux host officially available on the Internet for practicing penetration testing?

Tags: penetration-test

Is there any Windows/Linux host officially available on the Internet for practicing penetration testing?

I am having continuous trouble with Virtual-Box.

It is horribly slow to load and giving me lots of configuration troubles. Just eating up my time.

This is my machine:

[image]

Comment: There are many VM solutions out there - try another one. Do you think that a online host for anybody to hammer would be *faster*?

Comment: 4 Gig could be a bit low for running multiple VM's